# Not clcickable parent category in wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

How do a select which can not click on the parent category in wp_insert_post?

Example what i want http://fiddle.jshell.net/Pp7Ey/show/

Thx for answer!

```
   $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $cat = $_POST['cat'];

        $data = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $description,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_category' =>array($cat)
        );

wp_insert_post($data);
```

..

```
  <?php wp_dropdown_categories('orderby=name&hide_empty=0&show_count=1&show_option_none=Select one&class=cat&hierarchical=1&name=cat'); ?>
```

Comment: You can generate them using `<optgroup label="parent">`

Comment: can you give an example?